# Calculating power series of quantum operators on kets

Tags: matrix, series-expansion, physics, vector, quantum-computing

I am using the "[Quantum](https://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/)" add-on package to perform some quantum mechanical calculations using SU(1,1) generators. The code that I've developed reads

```
 Needs["Quantum`Notation`"]
 SetQuantumAliases[];

 Clear[J];
SetQuantumObject[J];
SetQuantumScalar[a, b];
Subscript[J, a_]\[CenterDot]Subscript[J, 0] := Subscript[J, a];
Subscript[J, 0]\[CenterDot]Subscript[J, b_] := Subscript[J, b];
(Subscript[J, a_])^2 := Subscript[J, 0];
Subscript[J, a_]\[CenterDot]Subscript[J, b_] := 
  KroneckerDelta[a, b] + I *\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(c\), \(3\)]\(Signature[{a, b, c}]*
\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(c\)]\)\);
\!\(\*
TagBox[
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"[[", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["J", "a_"], ",", 
SubscriptBox["J", "b_"]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "]]"}], "-"],
Quantum`Notation`zz050Commutator,
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) := I *\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(c\), \(3\)]\(Signature[{a, b, c}]*
\*SubscriptBox[\(J\), \(c\)]\)\);

\!\(\*
TagBox[
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"[[", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["J", "0"], ",", 
SubscriptBox["J", "+"]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "]]"}], "-"],
Quantum`Notation`zz050Commutator,
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) = SubPlus[J];
\!\(\*
TagBox[
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"[[", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["J", "0"], ",", 
SubscriptBox["J", "-"]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "]]"}], "-"],
Quantum`Notation`zz050Commutator,
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) = SubMinus[J];
\!\(\*
TagBox[
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"[[", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["J", "+"], ",", 
SubscriptBox["J", "-"]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "]]"}], "-"],
Quantum`Notation`zz050Commutator,
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) = 2*Subscript[J, 0];

DefineOperatorOnKets[Subscript[J, 0], {\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j_", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["n_", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) :> n \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", "n", ")"}], 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\)}]
DefineOperatorOnKets[SubPlus[J], {\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j_", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["n_", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) :> Sqrt[(n + 1) (j - n)] \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"n", "+", "1"}], ")"}], 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\)}]
DefineOperatorOnKets[SubMinus[J], {\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j_", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["n_", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) :> Sqrt[n (j - n + 1)] \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"n", "-", "1"}], ")"}], 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\)}]
```

I have also attached a screenshot of my code for better readability [image]

Having this script, I tried to evaluate $\exp[a J_{+} - bJ_{-}] | j, 0 \rangle$. Following the documentation on the power series of operators in [here](https://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/menunotation.html) and using the following script, I expanded the exponential to some order, say 2.

```
expande = 
  Normal[
   Series[
    Exp[(a*SubPlus[J] - b*SubMinus[J])], {SubPlus[J], 0, 
     2}, {SubMinus[J], 0, 2}]];
opt = expande // ExpandAll
opt\[CenterDot]\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["0", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) // Simplify
```

The outcome reads[image]
As it is evident from the screenshot, the action of some operators, such as $J_{-}J_{+} | j, 0 \rangle$, are not evaluated. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I didn't use this package. But from your output I guess Jplus and Jminus are not treated as quantum object correctly. You see the quantum objects are connected by `CenterDot` instead of `Times` while Jplus and Jminus are not. I guess the reason is that `Subscript[J,-]` is interpreted as `SubMinus[J]` automatically. Could you try by changing Jplus and Jminus to e.g. J_p and J_m?

Comment: Does this change give the correct result?  Instead of `(Subscript[J, a_])^2 := Subscript[J, 0]` define `Subscript[J, a_]\[CenterDot]Subscript[J, a_] := Subscript[J, 0]`  .  With this change, the result is $\frac{1}{4} \left(a^2 J_+^2+2 a
   J_++2\right) \left(b^2 J_-^2-2 b
   J_-+2\right)
   \left|j_{\hat{h}},0_{\hat{l}}\right\rangle$

Comment: @lilyric This suggestion is not compatible with the notation. This is because `a` and `b` are not operators and thus, `CenterDot` should not be used.

Comment: @LouisB Sadly, this also didn't help. I want my final results to be only expressed in terms of kets and no remaining $J_{\pm}$ operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simple: this package uses `CenterDot` as multiplication, while `Series` of `Exp` gives commutative polynomials wrt. `Times` instead of `CenterDot`.

The relevant codes are

```
Block[{Print},Needs["Quantum`Notation`"]];
SetQuantumAliases[];

SetQuantumObject[J];
SetQuantumScalar[a,b];

DefineOperatorOnKets[Subscript[J, 0], {\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j_", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["n_", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) :> n \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", "n", ")"}], 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\)}]
DefineOperatorOnKets[Subscript[J, p], {\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j_", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["n_", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) :> Sqrt[(n + 1) (j - n)] \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"n", "+", "1"}], ")"}], 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\)}]
DefineOperatorOnKets[Subscript[J, m], {\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j_", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["n_", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\) :> Sqrt[n (j - n + 1)] \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"n", "-", "1"}], ")"}], 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\)}]
```

[image]

Now let's define the non-commutative `Exp` as

```
opExp[op_,n_Integer]:=Sum[1/$$i! CenterDot@@Table[op,$$i],{$$i,0,n}]
```

Then we have the correct result,

```
op=opExp[(a Subscript[J, p]+b Subscript[J, m]),2]//ExpandAll
op\[CenterDot]\!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"\[VerticalSeparator]", 
TagBox[
RowBox[{
SubscriptBox["j", 
OverscriptBox["h", "^"]], ",", 
SubscriptBox["0", 
OverscriptBox["l", "^"]]}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080KetArgs,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> True},
Editable->True,
Selectable->True], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}],
Quantum`Notation`zz080Ket,
BaseStyle->{ShowSyntaxStyles -> False},
Editable->False,
Selectable->False]\)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This works! Thank you for your effort!